# how to deposit with foreign currency and receive anchor-issued token?

Tags: anchor, issuing

I want to build an anchor that issuing stablecoin named `LAOC` for my country currency and also providing deposit/withdrawal. But I have a question that:

1. How could my users deposit with foreign currency like USD, EUR,... and they receive that value in `LAOC` in their account ?
2. If it is possible, then how about the ratio between the currencies ?